# Съезжает футер вправо

Tags: html, css

На сайте http://typeblog.ru/ съезжает футер вправо в IE8 (не знаю, как в других). Никак не могу понять, почему. Помогите пожалуйста.
--
**Решено!**
Все оказалось проще. Надо было убрать height для футера выше

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это cработает для IE8(в ie9 точно работает): В файле css для футера ПОСЛЕ СТИЛЕЙ ДЛЯ НОРМАЛЬНЫХ БРАУЗЕРОВ прописывай отдельно стили для ie8 таким образом:

```
//margin-top: 111px;
//padding-left: 222%;
```

Именно через //

Может помочь следующее:

```
<!--[if IE 8]--><link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /><!--[endif]-->
```

Comment: нет, не помогает

Comment: @inferus-vv а так?

Answer (score 0):

Напишите, как должно быть.

```
float: left; // для родительского блока
position: inherit; // для дочернего блока
```

а дальше свойствами `top, right, left, bottom`. Попробуйте использовать CSS-хаки под различные версии браузеров. В поисковик по ключевым словам "CSS-хаки".